# Google Static Map API how to specify max zoom level

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

We have a report that shows where 2 markers are on a map, works great except when the markers are next to each other it zooms in to the highest level of zoom.

We want the min zoom to be open, but set the max zoom to a certain level. I have looked through the [Google Static Map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) documentation, and cant see where to do it.

Does anyone know if this is possible using the static map api?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Google does not have that feature in place. Here is a feature request:

Issue 3909
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3909

Please vote!

Answer (score 2):

Well it is sort of not straight forward to get it with static maps. You can omit specifying the zoom and hope google will choose what it thinks best.

Anyway this is how I got rid of it. I had my own zoom up / zoom down buttons to show up next to the map image. Upon click, I increase or decrease the current zoom value and reload the map image.

I know it's not pretty, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried that for static maps but it works for me in normal map:

```
google.maps.event.addListener($map, 'zoom_changed', function(){
if($map.getZoom()<4){$map.setZoom(4);}
if($map.getZoom()>14){$map.setZoom(14);}
});
```

Here I am limiting both max and min zoom.

Hope it helps

K

Answer (score 0):

http://maps.google.com/staticmap?markers=-21.7164,35.4384&size=640x640&key=your-api-key&format=png8&maptype=roadY&zoom=8

Note the zoom querystring parameter

Answer (score -1):

I found the following code from this URL:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
  });

Instead of adding listener, you could do document.onload(function() {
    map.setZoom(8));

Comment: Thanks for this, but it is not quite what I need. We have a report with multiple maps on it generated from the server. It needs to have any minimum zoom level, but set a maximum so it doesnt zoom right in to a level that you can get the context of where the markers are. The js API can set a max zoom, but I cant see hwo to do it with the static.